# Cannot import a function from a solidity smart contract script

Tags: solidity, python

[Here is the code. Basically the "getEntranceFee" part is not calling from the smart contract script, FundMe.sol.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWgb4.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWgb4.png)

[image]

Comment: Please reformat your question and post code instead of image. Text in images won't get indexed by google and it's impossible for people to copy your code and try it.

Answer (score 1):

By only calling `FundMe` you're not getting an actual instance of the smart contract. It only gets you `ContractContainer` as stated in the log.

If your contract has been already deployed, you can call `FundMe[x]` where `x` is the index of the deployed `FundMe` contract (All deployments are saved in array sequentially). If you always want to get the **latest** contract, you can just call `FundMe[-1]`